# Pentaho Report integration in Grails web Application

Tags: grails, pentaho

Pentaho RD version : 5.2.0.0-209
Requirement Show / Hide Fields in Pentaho Report Based on User Input

I have a requirement that invisible elements on the report should not consume any space in row or column.
so i use the banding element and the functionality formula to 'invisible consumes space'
I have used two bands one within another, with different layouts 'row' and 'block' to remove both spaces for invisible elements (in rows and columns).

Note It is giving appropriate result and working fine in Pentaho Report Desinger tool itself while updating Query to fetch any field either col1,col2 etc...

But Integration that .prpt report in Grails, it stil shows the "Invisible Consumes Space" in row and column both.

Please help me to remove both spaces for invisible elements (in rows and columns) while integrating the Report to Grails or any web application

Comment: Is any solution possible ?

Comment: If any one know the resolution then that would be great help to me !..